# jquery mobile scroll ghost tap

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I have a vertical list of Divs that  users scroll through on my Jquery Mobile page. It works great when Intertial scrolling is disabled, but when Intertial scrolling is on I'm getting ghost taps. I have a class and then a class:active that I user for the selector.

When I click without scrolling everything works perfectly, however if I am scrolling and the scroll has not yet completed, the div I was touching when I started scrolling briefly gets active and then unactive. It produces a very ugly flashing effect.

Anyone know how to fix this?